# RegEx Or and AND

Tags: php, regex

Hi I tired to use RegEx in PHP. The following elements I like to get with it:

```
<a="300">
<a="300"b="300">
<b="300">
```

The Problem is that I get only

```
<a="300">
<b="300">
```

with the following RegEx:

```
<(a|b)="[0-9]*">
```

What do I have to change, that I get all three elements? Is there a ANDOR operator?

Comment: Don't parse XML or HTML with regular expressions, use a [relevant parser](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

Comment: Why not? Are there security or performance issues?

Comment: Yes I suppose you could say that there are performance issues in that it's not possible. You can kludge it for a tag or two, but parsing full documents with regex will never happen in a sane manner.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your problem is rather a simple string processing than serious parsing, I would modify your regex like this:

```
<(a|b)="[0-9]+".*>
```

I added `.*` to allow characters inbetween `"` and `>`.

or a slightly my-flavored version:

```
<[ab]="\d+"[^>]*?>
```

- piping single characters with `|` are less favored over `[...]`
- `\d` is for series of digits
- `[^>]*?` for characters other than `>`

Answer (score 0):

You need an additional grouping, to specify, that you would accept multiple of that kind:

```
echo '<a="300">
<a="300"b="300">
<b="300">' | egrep '<((a|b)="[0-9]*")+>'
<a="300">
<a="300"b="300">
<b="300">
```

Comment: are you sure this is valid php?

Comment: No, it's only a valid RegEx in grep -E or sed and many other languages I know. But since in the example, there are nearly the same elements used, () and * while I use () and +. Does the + need masking, or what is your concern? CAustin uses the + too.

Comment: i guess my concern was simply its a php code question not being answered in php, I know regular expressions are language agnostic, but the OP was asking for a php solution.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is not boolean logic. The `|` symbol in regex is not an OR operator; it is referred to as alternation, which works similarly but is not quite the same thing. If you're just trying to match one of multiple characters, you should use square brackets `[]` to create a character set. In this case, `[ab]` matches `a` or `b`, just as `[0-9]` matches `0` or `1` or `2` etc.

Here's the pattern that I would suggest

`<[ab]="\d+"(?:[ab]="\d+")?>`

Comment: And now what is the difference of `(a|b)` and `[ab]`? Why shall we use square brackets?

Comment: It's a much less expensive operation, taking about half the number of logical steps to resolve. It's more concise since it doesn't require a character in between each option for the process to split on. Ranges are supported, so if you wanted to match a, b, c, or d, you can write `[a-d]` instead of `(a|b|c|d)`. It also doesn't create a [likely unwanted] capture group, which, with alternation, would have to be avoided by using `(?: )` instead of just `( )`.

Comment: What if I want to find width and height? Can I put these also in brackets?

Comment: @ThiKool I'm not sure what you mean by that. If you're talking about matching x and y in addition to a and b, yes that's possible. You can test it out here https://regex101.com/

Comment: @ThiKool no, `(?:width|length)` is a perfectly fine regex that matches either  of the words. Using charactergroups (`[]`) are no replacement for Alternations. So yes, the Example of CAustin lacks some solid answer, why to use `[ab]` over `(?:a|b)`, in the "real world".